# How to obtain the same performance of self-compiled OpenCV as the package from the repository

Tags: compiling, performance, opencv

I recently decided to compile OpenCV myself on my newer Ubuntu 18.04 machine (which previously had no installation of OpenCV whatsoever). However, I noticed severe performance drops out of software I've previously written which uses OpenCV and I eventually determined that the culprit was OpenCV itself. I then installed OpenCV with the `libopencv-dev` package and the performance matched, or was better than, what I had previously seen on other machines (on which I did not install OpenCV myself). I realize that the performance of OpenCV is heavily dependent on what I enable during compilation and that the repository package has perhaps been optimized for Ubuntu 18.04, however, that package restricts me to a specific version of OpenCV.

What I'd like to know is what I did wrong and what I should do during compilation in order achieve the same or similar performance as the repo package. The version of OpenCV I compiled was 3.4.3. Below I've included the output of `cmake -LA`.

```
ANT_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=ANT_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
Atlas_BLAS_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatlas.so
Atlas_CBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
Atlas_CBLAS_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcblas.so
Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=Atlas_CLAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
Atlas_LAPACK_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so
BLAS_Accelerate_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_Accelerate_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_acml_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_acml_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_acml_mp_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_acml_mp_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_atlas_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libatlas.so
BLAS_blas_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_blas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_complib.sgimath_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_complib.sgimath_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_cxml_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_cxml_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_dxml_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_dxml_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_essl_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_essl_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_f77blas_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libf77blas.so
BLAS_goto2_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_goto2_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_mkl_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_mkl_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_mkl_em64t_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_mkl_em64t_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_mkl_ia32_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_mkl_ia32_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_mkl_intel_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_mkl_intel_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_mkl_intel_lp64_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_mkl_intel_lp64_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_openblas_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_openblas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_scsl_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_scsl_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_sgemm_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_sgemm_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_sunperf_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_sunperf_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BLAS_vecLib_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=BLAS_vecLib_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
BUILD_CUDA_STUBS:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_DOCS:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_IPP_IW:BOOL=ON
BUILD_ITT:BOOL=ON
BUILD_JASPER:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_JAVA:BOOL=ON
BUILD_JPEG:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_LIST:STRING=
BUILD_OPENEXR:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_PACKAGE:BOOL=ON
BUILD_PERF_TESTS:BOOL=ON
BUILD_PNG:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_PROTOBUF:BOOL=ON
BUILD_SHARED_LIBS:BOOL=ON
BUILD_TBB:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_TESTS:BOOL=ON
BUILD_TIFF:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_USE_SYMLINKS:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_WEBP:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_WITH_DEBUG_INFO:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_WITH_DYNAMIC_IPP:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_ZLIB:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_opencv_apps:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_calib3d:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_core:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_dnn:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_features2d:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_flann:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_highgui:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_imgcodecs:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_imgproc:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_java_bindings_generator:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_js:BOOL=OFF
BUILD_opencv_ml:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_objdetect:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_photo:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_python_bindings_generator:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_shape:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_stitching:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_superres:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_ts:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_video:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_videoio:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_videostab:BOOL=ON
BUILD_opencv_world:BOOL=OFF
CCACHE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=CCACHE_PROGRAM-NOTFOUND
CLAMDBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=CLAMDBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
CLAMDBLAS_ROOT_DIR:PATH=CLAMDBLAS_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND
CLAMDFFT_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=CLAMDFFT_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
CLAMDFFT_ROOT_DIR:PATH=CLAMDFFT_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND
CMAKE_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ar
CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE:STRING=Release
CMAKE_COLOR_MAKEFILE:BOOL=ON
CMAKE_CONFIGURATION_TYPES:STRING=Debug;Release
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/c++
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ar-7
CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-7
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_C_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/cc
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_AR:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ar-7
CMAKE_C_COMPILER_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib-7
CMAKE_C_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=-g
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=-Os -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=-O3 -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=-O2 -g -DNDEBUG
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=
CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=
CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS:BOOL=OFF
CMAKE_INSTALL_BINDIR:PATH=bin
CMAKE_INSTALL_DATADIR:PATH=
CMAKE_INSTALL_DATAROOTDIR:PATH=share
CMAKE_INSTALL_DOCDIR:PATH=
CMAKE_INSTALL_INCLUDEDIR:PATH=include
CMAKE_INSTALL_INFODIR:PATH=
CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR:PATH=lib
CMAKE_INSTALL_LIBEXECDIR:PATH=libexec
CMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALEDIR:PATH=
CMAKE_INSTALL_LOCALSTATEDIR:PATH=var
CMAKE_INSTALL_MANDIR:PATH=
CMAKE_INSTALL_OLDINCLUDEDIR:PATH=/usr/include
CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH=/home/telerobotics/frameworks/opencv-3.4
CMAKE_INSTALL_RUNSTATEDIR:PATH=
CMAKE_INSTALL_SBINDIR:PATH=sbin
CMAKE_INSTALL_SHAREDSTATEDIR:PATH=com
CMAKE_INSTALL_SYSCONFDIR:PATH=etc
CMAKE_LINKER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ld
CMAKE_MAKE_PROGRAM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/make
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=
CMAKE_MODULE_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=
CMAKE_NM:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/nm
CMAKE_OBJCOPY:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/objcopy
CMAKE_OBJDUMP:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/objdump
CMAKE_RANLIB:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/ranlib
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=
CMAKE_SHARED_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=
CMAKE_SKIP_INSTALL_RPATH:BOOL=OFF
CMAKE_SKIP_RPATH:BOOL=OFF
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS:STRING=
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=
CMAKE_STATIC_LINKER_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=
CMAKE_STRIP:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/strip
CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE:BOOL=OFF
CPACK_BINARY_DEB:BOOL=OFF
CPACK_BINARY_FREEBSD:BOOL=OFF
CPACK_BINARY_IFW:BOOL=OFF
CPACK_BINARY_NSIS:BOOL=OFF
CPACK_BINARY_RPM:BOOL=OFF
CPACK_BINARY_STGZ:BOOL=ON
CPACK_BINARY_TBZ2:BOOL=OFF
CPACK_BINARY_TGZ:BOOL=ON
CPACK_BINARY_TXZ:BOOL=OFF
CPACK_BINARY_TZ:BOOL=ON
CPACK_SOURCE_RPM:BOOL=OFF
CPACK_SOURCE_TBZ2:BOOL=ON
CPACK_SOURCE_TGZ:BOOL=ON
CPACK_SOURCE_TXZ:BOOL=ON
CPACK_SOURCE_TZ:BOOL=ON
CPACK_SOURCE_ZIP:BOOL=OFF
CPU_BASELINE:STRING=SSE3
CPU_DISPATCH:STRING=SSE4_1;SSE4_2;AVX;FP16;AVX2;AVX512_SKX
CUDA_64_BIT_DEVICE_CODE:BOOL=ON
CUDA_ATTACH_VS_BUILD_RULE_TO_CUDA_FILE:BOOL=ON
CUDA_BUILD_CUBIN:BOOL=OFF
CUDA_BUILD_EMULATION:BOOL=OFF
CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=CUDA_CUDART_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=CUDA_CUDA_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
CUDA_GENERATED_OUTPUT_DIR:PATH=
CUDA_HOST_COMPILATION_CPP:BOOL=ON
CUDA_HOST_COMPILER:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/cc
CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=CUDA_NVCC_EXECUTABLE-NOTFOUND
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS:STRING=
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_DEBUG:STRING=
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_MINSIZEREL:STRING=
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELEASE:STRING=
CUDA_NVCC_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO:STRING=
CUDA_PROPAGATE_HOST_FLAGS:BOOL=ON
CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR:PATH=CUDA_SDK_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND
CUDA_SEPARABLE_COMPILATION:BOOL=OFF
CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE:PATH=CUDA_TOOLKIT_INCLUDE-NOTFOUND
CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR:PATH=CUDA_TOOLKIT_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND
CUDA_VERBOSE_BUILD:BOOL=OFF
CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=CUDA_cublas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
CUDA_cublasemu_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=CUDA_cublasemu_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
CUDA_cufft_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=CUDA_cufft_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
CUDA_cufftemu_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=CUDA_cufftemu_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
CV_DISABLE_OPTIMIZATION:BOOL=OFF
CV_ENABLE_INTRINSICS:BOOL=ON
CV_TRACE:BOOL=ON
EIGEN_INCLUDE_PATH:PATH=/home/telerobotics/frameworks/eigen3.3.5
ENABLE_BUILD_HARDENING:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_CCACHE:BOOL=ON
ENABLE_COVERAGE:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_CXX11:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_FAST_MATH:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_FLAKE8:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_GNU_STL_DEBUG:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_IMPL_COLLECTION:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_INSTRUMENTATION:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_LTO:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_NOISY_WARNINGS:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_OMIT_FRAME_POINTER:BOOL=ON
ENABLE_PIC:BOOL=ON
ENABLE_PRECOMPILED_HEADERS:BOOL=ON
ENABLE_PROFILING:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_PYLINT:BOOL=OFF
ENABLE_SOLUTION_FOLDERS:BOOL=OFF
EXECUTABLE_OUTPUT_PATH:PATH=/home/telerobotics/frameworks/opencv-src/build-opencv-3.4/bin
GENERATE_ABI_DESCRIPTOR:BOOL=OFF
GIT_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/git
HAVE_IEEEFP:STRING=1
HOST_BIG_ENDIAN:STRING=OFF
HOST_FILLORDER:STRING=FILLORDER_LSB2MSB
INSTALL_CREATE_DISTRIB:BOOL=OFF
INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES:BOOL=OFF
INSTALL_TESTS:BOOL=OFF
INSTALL_TO_MANGLED_PATHS:BOOL=OFF
JASPER_LIBRARY_DEBUG:FILEPATH=JASPER_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
JASPER_LIBRARY_RELEASE:FILEPATH=JASPER_LIBRARY_RELEASE-NOTFOUND
JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH:PATH=JAVA_AWT_INCLUDE_PATH-NOTFOUND
JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=JAVA_AWT_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH:PATH=JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH-NOTFOUND
JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2:PATH=JAVA_INCLUDE_PATH2-NOTFOUND
JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=JAVA_JVM_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include
JPEG_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so
LAPACKE_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=LAPACKE_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
LAPACK_Accelerate_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=LAPACK_Accelerate_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
LAPACK_CBLAS_H:STRING=
LAPACK_IMPL:STRING=Unknown
LAPACK_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=
LAPACK_LAPACKE_H:STRING=
LAPACK_LIBRARIES:STRING=
LAPACK_goto2_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=LAPACK_goto2_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
LAPACK_lapack_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblapack.so
LAPACK_openblas_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=LAPACK_openblas_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
LAPACK_vecLib_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=LAPACK_vecLib_LIBRARY-NOTFOUND
MKL_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=MKL_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND/include
MKL_LAPACKE_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=MKL_LAPACKE_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
MKL_ROOT_DIR:PATH=MKL_ROOT_DIR-NOTFOUND
MKL_WITH_OPENMP:BOOL=ON
MKL_WITH_TBB:BOOL=OFF
M_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so
OPENCL_FOUND:BOOL=ON
OPENCL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/telerobotics/frameworks/opencv-src/opencv/3rdparty/include/opencl/1.2
OPENCL_LIBRARY:STRING=
OPENCV_CONFIG_FILE_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/home/telerobotics/frameworks/opencv-src/build-opencv-3.4
OPENCV_DNN_OPENCL:BOOL=ON
OPENCV_DOWNLOAD_PATH:PATH=/home/telerobotics/frameworks/opencv-src/opencv/.cache
OPENCV_DUMP_HOOKS_FLOW:BOOL=OFF
OPENCV_ENABLE_NONFREE:BOOL=OFF
OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH:PATH=
OPENCV_FORCE_3RDPARTY_BUILD:BOOL=OFF
OPENCV_GENERATE_PKGCONFIG:BOOL=ON
OPENCV_GENERATE_SETUPVARS:BOOL=ON
OPENCV_PYTHON3_VERSION:BOOL=OFF
OPENCV_TIMESTAMP:STRING=2018-11-08T22:06:56Z
OPENCV_WARNINGS_ARE_ERRORS:BOOL=OFF
OPENEXR_HALF_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so
OPENEXR_IEX_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so
OPENEXR_ILMIMF_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so
OPENEXR_ILMTHREAD_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so
OPENEXR_IMATH_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so
OPENEXR_INCLUDE_PATH:PATH=/usr/include/OpenEXR
OPENEXR_INCLUDE_PATHS:PATH=/usr/include/OpenEXR
OPENEXR_LIBRARIES:STRING=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libImath.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmImf.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIex.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libHalf.so;/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libIlmThread.so
OPENGL_EGL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=OPENGL_EGL_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
OPENGL_GLX_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include
OPENGL_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include
OPENGL_egl_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libEGL.so
OPENGL_gl_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGL.so
OPENGL_glu_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLU.so
OPENGL_glx_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libGLX.so
OPENGL_opengl_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libOpenGL.so
OPENGL_xmesa_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=OPENGL_xmesa_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
OpenBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=OpenBLAS_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
OpenBLAS_LIB:FILEPATH=OpenBLAS_LIB-NOTFOUND
OpenCV_HAL_DIR:PATH=OpenCV_HAL_DIR-NOTFOUND
OpenMP_CXX_FLAGS:STRING=-fopenmp
OpenMP_CXX_LIB_NAMES:STRING=gomp;pthread
OpenMP_C_FLAGS:STRING=-fopenmp
OpenMP_C_LIB_NAMES:STRING=gomp;pthread
OpenMP_gomp_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/7/libgomp.so
OpenMP_pthread_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so
PKG_CONFIG_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/pkg-config
PNG_LIBRARY_DEBUG:FILEPATH=PNG_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
PNG_LIBRARY_RELEASE:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so
PNG_PNG_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include
PROTOBUF_UPDATE_FILES:BOOL=OFF
PYTHON2_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python2.7
PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=
PYTHON2_INCLUDE_DIR2:PATH=
PYTHON2_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=
PYTHON2_LIBRARY_DEBUG:FILEPATH=
PYTHON2_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=
PYTHON2_PACKAGES_PATH:PATH=lib/python2.7/dist-packages
PYTHON3_EXECUTABLE:FILEPATH=/usr/bin/python3
PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=
PYTHON3_INCLUDE_DIR2:PATH=
PYTHON3_LIBRARY:FILEPATH=
PYTHON3_LIBRARY_DEBUG:FILEPATH=
PYTHON3_NUMPY_INCLUDE_DIRS:PATH=
PYTHON3_PACKAGES_PATH:PATH=lib/python3.6/dist-packages
TBB_DIR:PATH=TBB_DIR-NOTFOUND
TBB_ENV_INCLUDE:PATH=/usr/include
TBB_ENV_LIB:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtbb.so
TBB_ENV_LIB_DEBUG:FILEPATH=TBB_ENV_LIB_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
TBB_VER_FILE:FILEPATH=/usr/include/tbb/tbb_stddef.h
TIFF_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
TIFF_LIBRARY_DEBUG:FILEPATH=TIFF_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
TIFF_LIBRARY_RELEASE:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtiff.so
USE_WIN32_FILEIO:BOOL=OFF
VTK_DIR:PATH=VTK_DIR-NOTFOUND
WEBP_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=WEBP_INCLUDE_DIR-NOTFOUND
WITH_1394:BOOL=ON
WITH_ARAVIS:BOOL=OFF
WITH_ARITH_DEC:BOOL=ON
WITH_ARITH_ENC:BOOL=ON
WITH_CLP:BOOL=OFF
WITH_CUBLAS:BOOL=ON
WITH_CUDA:BOOL=OFF
WITH_CUFFT:BOOL=ON
WITH_EIGEN:BOOL=ON
WITH_FFMPEG:BOOL=ON
WITH_GDAL:BOOL=OFF
WITH_GDCM:BOOL=OFF
WITH_GIGEAPI:BOOL=OFF
WITH_GPHOTO2:BOOL=OFF
WITH_GSTREAMER:BOOL=ON
WITH_GSTREAMER_0_10:BOOL=OFF
WITH_GTK:BOOL=ON
WITH_GTK_2_X:BOOL=OFF
WITH_HALIDE:BOOL=OFF
WITH_IMGCODEC_HDR:BOOL=ON
WITH_IMGCODEC_PXM:BOOL=ON
WITH_IMGCODEC_SUNRASTER:BOOL=ON
WITH_INF_ENGINE:BOOL=OFF
WITH_IPP:BOOL=ON
WITH_ITT:BOOL=ON
WITH_JASPER:BOOL=ON
WITH_JPEG:BOOL=ON
WITH_LAPACK:BOOL=ON
WITH_LIBV4L:BOOL=ON
WITH_MFX:BOOL=OFF
WITH_NVCUVID:BOOL=ON
WITH_OPENCL:BOOL=ON
WITH_OPENCLAMDBLAS:BOOL=ON
WITH_OPENCLAMDFFT:BOOL=ON
WITH_OPENCL_SVM:BOOL=OFF
WITH_OPENEXR:BOOL=ON
WITH_OPENGL:BOOL=ON
WITH_OPENMP:BOOL=ON
WITH_OPENNI:BOOL=OFF
WITH_OPENNI2:BOOL=OFF
WITH_OPENVX:BOOL=OFF
WITH_PNG:BOOL=ON
WITH_PROTOBUF:BOOL=ON
WITH_PTHREADS_PF:BOOL=ON
WITH_PVAPI:BOOL=OFF
WITH_QT:BOOL=OFF
WITH_QUIRC:BOOL=ON
WITH_TBB:BOOL=ON
WITH_TIFF:BOOL=ON
WITH_UNICAP:BOOL=OFF
WITH_V4L:BOOL=ON
WITH_VA:BOOL=OFF
WITH_VA_INTEL:BOOL=OFF
WITH_VTK:BOOL=ON
WITH_WEBP:BOOL=ON
WITH_XIMEA:BOOL=OFF
WITH_XINE:BOOL=OFF
ZLIB_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=/usr/include
ZLIB_LIBRARY_DEBUG:FILEPATH=ZLIB_LIBRARY_DEBUG-NOTFOUND
ZLIB_LIBRARY_RELEASE:FILEPATH=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
ccitt:BOOL=ON
logluv:BOOL=ON
lzw:BOOL=ON
mdi:BOOL=ON
next:BOOL=ON
old-jpeg:BOOL=OFF
opencv_dnn_PERF_CAFFE:BOOL=OFF
opencv_dnn_PERF_CLCAFFE:BOOL=OFF
packbits:BOOL=ON
thunder:BOOL=ON
```

Comment: A quick lookover shows a lot of missing libraries.  Those missing libraries prevent your compiled binary from having [potentially] all of the libraries found in the official binary.  While it is true that you may see improvements by removing unused code and features, many of the modules you're missing seem to deal with hardware and hardware acceleration and the lacking of these modules is likely the reason your binary is not as performant.  Can you compare  to `pkg-config --cflags opencv` or similar?

Comment: That's kinda what I expected and there doesn't really seem to be any tutorial online that details the hardware acceleration libraries that are necessary. Most of them just have you install codecs and maybe TBB. By "compare to `pkg-config --cflags opencv` or similar" do you mean compare my cmake settings to the ones used in the repo version?

Comment: Yeah, I don't have an exact path to provide, but you can look at how it is built by the maintainer if there are no other details available.  Also, some of these strings are pretty unique, so by looking up something like **"BLAS_vecLib_LIBRARY:FILEPATH"**, you can find other configurations and examples.  Most people probably get OpenCV compiled and don't realize they are missing these critical libs, so be careful of that.  If you can provide more insight as to why you'd prefer to compile yourself, maybe others are in a similar situation and have a slightly different idea on how to solve it.

Comment: Really the only reason (I can think of) to compile myself would be to have access to a newer version. It used to be that in order to gain access to the `contrib` portion of the library, you would have to compile it yourself (and that may still be the case on Windows) but it looks like the `libopencv-dev` repo package in Ubuntu includes those libraries. Honestly, I'm happy with the repo version, I just can't stand not knowing what I did wrong.

Comment: Also, I think your hardware is important.  [This example](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/10/09/optimizing-opencv-on-the-raspberry-pi/) optimizes for Raspberry Pi hardware.  What's your CPU and Graphics setup? **CUDA** and **nvcc** are both graphics hardware accelerations, so you can focus on those if it makes sense for your hardware.  It seems like you're falling back to **OpenGL**, which is good but you might be able to do better.  You can look at `lspci` to get relevant details about your system hardware.

Comment: You make a good point. I have an Intel Core i5-4440 and it looks like its just the integrated Intel Haswell graphics. The fact that I get both levels of performance on the exact same machine with different builds suggests that it's not a hardware capability issue, but the repo build certainly may be using graphics accelerations that I am not.

Comment: The output you provided shows that **CUDA** and **nvcc** libraries are not available.  They are most likely provided in the official build, so if you have hardware that would take advantage of this, lacking these libraries in your build would mean that your build would be less performant.  So, if you want to look into getting a similar build, you'll have to define a success condition which will include determining your hardware and which libraries to build/download as a prerequisite to building OpenCV.  Best of luck!